# Does being 'allied' with a companion give you any benefits?

Tags: starfield

In "Starfield", I've completed the companion quest for two of my companions: Barrett and Sarah Morgan. Once I completed each quest, a small message displayed saying that the companion was now my ally.

I can't seem to figure out if this means anything, though. The 'status' page doesn't seem to indicate anything tied to this new state. And googling 'starfield ally' seems to bring up compatibility q&a's regarding an ASUS handheld unfortunately named 'ally'.

Since a message is displayed, I'm inclined to believe there's some sort of benefit inherent in being an ally with a given companion character -- possibly similar to Fallout 4 where different characters, once you maxed out their regard for you and became their ally, gave you special benefits (eg. extra damage against robots, that sort of thing.) **What, if anything, is the benefit to being an "ally" with a companion, and are those benefits displayed somewhere?**

Comment: I don't know about ally, but being romantically `[Committed]` increases the XP boost of resting from 5% to 15%.

Comment: also, after the rest, the allied character will be laying on the same bed with you and make comments insinuating stuff happened

Comment: No that's only if you're in a relationship (eg have been flirting) @Icebone1000 ; if you're just friendly that doesn't happen.